# Filtering by entries which have unpublished draft versions in the admin

Tags: entries, control-panel, user-interface

I have a client who wants to use an author (draft) -> editor (publish) workflow.

It appears that authors can update existing entries which will create a new draft of the entry. As an editor, I can then visit the edit page for that entry and select the new draft from the "revisions" drop-down.

This is great if I know that a new draft is waiting to be reviewed, but I couldn't find a way to discover which entries have new drafts.

Is there a way to view which posts have new drafts from the entries index? Otherwise what is the normal practice for editor-type users to know which entries have pending changes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft definitely doesn't give you these filtering tools when viewing a list of entries, but the building blocks exist within the framework to allow you to build your own solution. The most straightforward way I can think of would be to create a plugin with its own CP section and show the outstanding drafts there.

You can get a list of all drafts with this little bit of PHP:

```
EntryDraftRecord::model()->findAll();
```

If you expose the list of drafts using a [Template Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables), you could then display links to each of them by doing this:

```
{% set drafts = craft.myPlugin.getAllDrafts() %}

<ul>
{% for draft in drafts %}
    {% set draftEntry = craft.entries.getEntryById(draft.entryId)|first %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ draftEntry.getCpEditUrl() }}">{{ draftEntry.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```